# MXML Tutorials and Guides?

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml

I saw [this thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/830524)... I have passed by this whole MXML thing since it started...but I have grown tired of trying to manage my own UI in as3 and heard that it manages this. Where would one go to learn some tutorials on how to use MXML and Flex/FlashBuilder? I am oldschool and have been using Flash since CS2 and Flash Develop since CS3.

Comment: Just try Flex/Flash Builder, it allows to switch between design mode and source mode, the MXML concept is easy to understand when you see it.

Comment: @Organis afaik "design view" was removed from Flash Builder starting with v 4.7. I've stayed with v 4.6 because of this. Yet another Bad Move™ from Adobe.

Comment: @NoGrabbing Oh really. I wonder what was the point of it. I worked with MXML years ago and this thing is kinda twice as useless without design mode.

Comment: @Organis – yeah, I completely agree – but Adobe ditched Flex not that long after Flash Builder 4.7 came out so they were likely cutting corners. Being able to quickly see a layout without having to compile and run is darn useful.

Comment: @quantomworks I recommend studying this app: https://github.com/PhantomAppDevelopment/kaec-app It uses very simple MXML and it's a good starting point for making a mobile app. I recommend to use Flash Builder 4.6 so you can see in real time the effects of MXML in a project.

Comment: MXML probably isn't really a silver bullet in general.  The closer your application handles like a .NET desktop application with typical buttons, checkboxes, etc. though, the more useful Flex and MXML will be.  One thing to remember with MXML is that even the attributes tend pretty much always allow you to add AS3 code; sometimes they'll require you to wrap that code in `{` and `}` to clarify that it's not a hard-coded string value, and sometimes they'll just let you throw the code right in to the attribute.

Comment: But one thing to remember with MXML: If you try to bind something to a field or property in the class (if you're actually trying to have the MXML read live updates to the value in that field/property), then make sure that field/property actually is bindable.  The best I remember, any of the properties on the other Flex components in your project will already be bindable, so it's mainly an issue for fields and properties in your own, non-MXML, AS3 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was learning Flex, I used the [Flex in a Week](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html) tutorial.  I still sometimes go back and reference it.

It's a good place to start, but after you get some Flex under your belt nothing beats just trying things out!

Comment: Will this tut teach me in a weekend and let me apply to my existing class files and services if I am already completely familiar with as3?

Comment: When I came in I didn't have any AS3 experience.  The "Flex in a Week" is the name, but I found that it didn't take nearly that long to pick up on the Flex framework.  You'll probably find any existing UI classes you have will need reworking to fit into Flex - but as said, since I didn't come in with previous AS3, I didn't have any baggage to worry about...